# Editing text file in python

Tags: python

I have a text file that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE address(

    location_pk integer NULL,

    City varchar(50) NULL, 

    Address1 varchar(50) NULL, 

    Address2 varchar(50) NULL, 

CREATE TABLE name(

    idinteger NULL,

    City varchar(50) NULL, 

    RootDCTKey integer NULL, 

    Class varchar(50) NULL, 

CREATE TABLE location(

    location_pk integer NULL,

    City varchar(50) NULL, 

    Rootkey integer NULL,
```

I need to add a  ");" and delete the comma',' after each end of table do that it look like :

```
CREATE TABLE address(

    location_pk integer NULL,

    City varchar(50) NULL, 

    Address1 varchar(50) NULL, 

    Address2 varchar(50) NULL ); 

CREATE TABLE name(

    idinteger NULL,

    City varchar(50) NULL, 

    RootDCTKey integer NULL, 

    Class varchar(50) NULL );

CREATE TABLE location(

    location_pk integer NULL,

    City varchar(50) NULL, 

    Rootkey integer NULL );
```

My approach is to write the corrected version of the file to another file

```
opFile1 = open('txtfile.txt','rb').readlines()
finalfile = open('finaltxtfile.txt','wb')

for i,line in enumerate(opFile1):

    if not line.startswith('CREATE TABLE'):
        finalfile.write(line)
    else:
        #overwrite the last written line with the corrected line
        finalfile.write(opFile1[i-2].rstrip(',')+' );')

        #write the original 'CREATE TABLE' line
        finalfile.write(line)
```

This approach just adds the corrected line before the CREATE TABLE line and do not remove the original wrong line. Please help with your ideas. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps. For each line,with the help of enumerated index, check if the next-to-the next line starts with `CREATE` (I have made it CREATE, you can modify the string as your need). If yes, perform the replacement `line.replace(',',');')` and write the line. We also need to replace for the last line; This is added as a condition in the if as `or i+1==len(opFile1)`. The `i+2<len(opFile1)` is there so that the index is prevented from going out of bounds.

```
opFile1 = open('txtfile.txt','r').readlines()
finalfile = open('finaltxtfile.txt','w')

for i,line in enumerate(opFile1):
    if i+2<len(opFile1) and opFile1[i+2].startswith('CREATE') or i+1==len(opFile1):
        finalfile.write(line.replace(',',');'))
    else:
        finalfile.write(line)
finalfile.close()
```

Btw, you were using binary modes `rb`, `wb` to write the string which is unnecessary, I have changed it to normal modes `r` and `w`.

Comment: it's a detail, but files are not closed at the end, maybe add a `with open('txtfile.txt','r')...`

Comment: @PRMoureu Thank you. I added the `close()`

Answer (score 1):

If the file isn't huge I wouldn't bother processing each line.  I would just read the entire file into a variable, do a find/replace on the last comma, and then write the variable to a new file (or the original file).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `re` to make the job:

```
finalfile.write(re.sub(b'NULL,(\s*\n*)(CREATE|\Z)', rb'NULL);\1\2', opFile1))
```